# Doing INSERT using mysqli_query corrupts utf-8 encoding (Converts to question marks)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mysqli

I am migrating my database using two connections (one to old and other to the new).
On both the connections I am executing:

- `mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");`
- `mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES utf8");`

Also the PHP file has fileencoding set to utf-8 using the following commands in vim :

- `:set bomb`
- `:set fileencoding=utf-8`
- `:wq`

Both the source and destination tables have respective fields set to "utf8_general_ci" collation.

The source is on MySql 5.0 and destination is on MySql 5.5

I am also using mysqli_real_escape_string on the content that is extracted from source.

The above steps don't seem to work as unicode data (in utf-8 encoding) gets converted to question marks in the destination. What is that I am doing wrong?

(Please also note that, I can not directly import the data in the destination as the table structure is changing.)

Comment: How do you know there are actually question marks in the database. Are you sure it isn't the viewing of the DB that corrupts the data?

Answer (score 0):

> Both the source and destination tables have respective fields set to "utf8_general_ci" collation.

Looks like destination table doesn't

Comment: Verified it again. Both the source and destination fields are set to utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem:

Though the fields and the tables were set to "utf8_general_ci" collation, the Database itself was set to "latin1_swedish_ci" collation.

Changed the collation to "utf8_general_ci" and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Database encoding doesn't affect particular fields. And change of database encoding won't affect existing fields or tables ever.